# how to extend asp.net application in this scenario

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net web application.where i am creating the User as registration for a particular Firm.In this firm there are 3 type of user as of now. as Admin, Dealer, Manager. so according to this I am changing the UI page.

Means When  Admin (Admin is default entry) going  create let say Dealer, then there is different UI except General information fields (like name ,contact details and all). and when creating the manager there is different UI fields, except than General information fields.

To reuse the page i am using this way , when selected Manager then related his UI fields get only visible, same for dealer. obviously there is a dropdown control from where i am selecting User type.

But some how , later on if one more User type get added by firm, I need to generate functionality according to New User type. how can i handle if I don not want to change existing code. sense is how can i write the generic code so that I should not need to change in code behind or in javascript again.

Where as all this things are in planning and under implementation for now. but before to go a head I must clear this thing. I am planning to change the UI structure in javascript as usual way , i means

`if selected User Type is "Dealer then make visible these div's ELSE If User Type is Manager then make visible these divs`

I want to write generic javacript , though new user type get added.

Comment: Please reply me here , I am in doubt are you guys getting my question or this is unanswered thing

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Membership/Role Provider?

Comment: No, I am not using asp.net membership / role provider. i have developed my own module. will that affects something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain the field <-> user type relation in a database and dynamically add labels and textboxes in the PageLoad of your Page.

Then when a new type of user comes along you'd simply need to add to your data.
Your user type should also be in a database.

Of course, the code that lets your users create other users would also have to be flexible enough. So you'd need a CanCreate table that dictates who can create what type of user. :)

**EDIT** Expanded how to build your Content

Actually, I like your idea about storing the html elements in the database. That'd save you using reflection to dynamically get the propertyvalue. However, I don't think you'll be able to use databinding and all that.

So instead I'd do something like this:

```
public enum ControlType
{
    Label,
    TextBox,
    ...
}
```

Make a table something like

- UserType
- PropertyName
- PropertyLabelName
- FieldLabelType (int)
- FieldContentType (int)

Then on pageload you get the UserType, pull the data from the table, find the div where you want to put the data and then add the controls like:

```
(pseudocode)

Control label = null;
switch (FieldLabelType)
{
    case ControlType.Label:
        var label = new Label()
        {
            .. all kinds of properties
            Text = PropertyLabelName
        };
        control = label;
        break;
    case ???
        ...
}
if (label != null)
    fielddiv.Add(label);

Control field = null;
switch (FieldContentType)
{
    case ControlType.TextBox:
        var textbox = new TextBox()
        {
            .. all kinds of properties
            Text = new Binding( ... Path = PropertyName)
        };
        control = textbox;
        break;
    case ???
}
if (field != null)
    fielddiv.Add(field);
```

Of course, you'd need to do some positioning to get it all looking pretty. Perhaps chuck in a table or something in code?

Comment: yes , but some where i need to check always which UI controls for which user type. so in real i need to check manually like If UserType=="Dealer" { makeVisibleDealerDiv();} else if UserType =="Manager" { makeVisibleManagerDiv()}else{MakeVisibleNormalDiv()}...like that. My question in I want do not want to check like this with specific UserType hardcode. this should be happened in generic way. is this passible?

Comment: My answer suggests nothing of the kind. Please re-read more closely.

Comment: Thanks... Yes, I have maintained the UserTypes in the database as you have said. but as you said there I need to add dynamically populate labels and text boxes. but on which basis. I need to check somewhere , right ? as my comment. Well do you mean to say I need to maintain the UI items in html string format in database?  may be you are right , but I could not get your answer .please clear me. guide me